# grey out app icon puzzle

Tags: android, process, icons

I use those code to grey out a icon of RunningAppProcessInfo, but cause some side effect that all icon in other list greyed out too! SUP? Any solutions?

```
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        if (_isChecked) {
            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(0);
            icon.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about a ListView here or something then do it like this:

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon); 
if (_isChecked) { 
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(); 
    cm.setSaturation(0); 
    icon.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm)); 
} 
else {
    // Reset saturation to normal here
}
```

Reason for this being that views are reused in a ListView for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes，I did what you say in list1, but still has side effect in list2:
fact : seems all RunningAppProcessInfo shared only the same icon.

```
        if (_isChecked) {

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(1);
            icon.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));

        } else {
            appName.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            whitelist_item_type_tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

            ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
            cm.setSaturation(0);
            icon.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));

        }
```